# Lorenz attractor power spectrum

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes, differential-equations, chaos

If considered Lorenz attractor (with classical parameters $\sigma = 10, b = \frac{8}{3},r>25$), it is often noted, that while the spectral density (Fourier transformation of corresponding autocorrelation function) of $x$ and $y$ is usually more o less similar to the noise spectra (excluding windows periodicity), the power spectrum of $z$ usually has well pronounced peak ([Farmer et al.,1980](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/~chaos/papers/Farmer.NYAS1980.pdf); [Alvarez et al.,2004](http://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0406031)). Nowadays this can be easily observed using numeric experiments. This peak can be associated with z-periodic structure of the attractor, that appears from the symmetry of the equations and the whole geometrical structure. Could someone give me a link (or, perhaps, an explanation) for some analytical results, that would illustrate the presence of these peak and give a way to estimate peak parameters (position, amplitude, width)? 
Sincerely